# jQuery File Upload blueimpl browser freeze

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

Im using Jquery File Upload bluempl for uploading files.
When i upload lot of number of files like 6000 files using this plugin the browser hangs and freeze many times, alothough when visiting the folder in server/files i can see the files been uploaded.
can you tell what kind of optimization or parameter i can use for uploading many files without the browser freeze.
Im using as example the one in basic.hml of the example file :

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io' ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like synchronous upload is the default in blueimp.

Browser freezes have often to do with synchronous instead of asynchronous javascript requests.

<s>Blueimp describes how to upload asynchronously:</s>
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Submit-files-asynchronously

**Update**

1. Ok, the add method described on the page above is just called when files are added to the queue
2. The [options documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options) contains parameters `sequentialUploads` and `limitConcurrentUploads`, please try using them or one of them.

Comment: but how to send asynchronously there's no example of that,should i add a parameter or  just by defining the add function like this  : add: function (e, data) {
  data.submit();
  }

Comment: thank u it worked when i put  sequentialUploads:true. Thank u